# Unable to deploy JAX-WS webservice in WAS 6.1

Tags: jax-ws

I have created a hello world webservice using JAX-WS. using wsimport tool created server side sceletons class from WSDL.I tried to deply the application in Webservice Application Server 6.0.0.3 .But not able to get the WSDL on browser.It is throwing 404 error.Can you please help me out how to solve the problem without adding any fix pack to the server.

Comment: There is some log that show if the service was correctly deployed? What URL are you using to access your service WSDL? ... Give us something to work on!

Answer (score 1):

WAS 6.1 does not support JAX-WS, unless you have the webservices feature pack installed.  You will have to use JAX-RPC instead.

WAS 7 is the first version that supports JAX-WS.

Answer (score 0):

Further Reading:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264563

the features that you need **are not available off-the-shelf in WAS 6.1**:

*What is offered in the WebSphere Application Server V6.1 Feature Pack for Web Services?*

-Web Services Reliable Messaging (WS-RM) 
-Web Services Addressing (WS-Addressing) 
-SOAP Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) 
-Web Services Secure Conversations (WS-SC) 
-New standards-based programming model support: 
-Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS 2.0) 
-Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB 2.0) 
-SOAP with Attachments API for Java (SAAJ 1.3) 
-Streaming API for XML (StAX 1.0)